# Sorting information from a file in python

Tags: python, sorting, text-files

I have a `.txt` file that has the following information in it that displays a users name and then 3 scores that they have scored in a quiz:

```
callum,10,7,9
carl,10,10,10
hollie,1,4,7
brad,4,8,3
kyle,7,2,0
```

I would like to `sort` it into alphabetical order displaying the users highest score after their name.

Comment: I have opened the txt file by using : file = open('scores.txt', 'r')

Comment: Give more information on input file. callum,10,7,9 and carl,10,10,10 are on same line??

Comment: No each different user is on a separate line, it wont let me post a picture though because i dont have enough rep

Comment: @Neenan37 It's probably going to flag as unclear what you asking

Comment: @Neenan37 Because too many informations are missing. You have to show us some codes here. How is your input-output etc. Instead of trying to explain them in comments, write them in your question please.

Comment: @howaboutNO im asking here because i dont know what code i need to use

Comment: `I have opened the txt file by using : file = open('scores.txt', 'r') –  Neenan37` again, you should write it in your question.

Comment: @howaboutNO shall i add that to my question then?

Comment: can you give more details on output? or you got your solution?

Answer (score 1):

1. Read file content.
2. Use `readlines()` method to read lines from file.
3. Use `split()` to get Name and score.
4. Add in dictionary:  `Name` is `Key` and `Value` is total score.
5. Get all `keys` from the result dictionary.
6. User `sort()` method to sort list by alphabets.
7. Print result by alphabets order.

Code

```
p = "/home/vivek/Desktop/test_input.txt"
result = {}
with open(p, "rb") as fp:
    for i in fp.readlines():
        tmp = i.split(",")
        try:
            result[(tmp[0])] = eval(tmp[1]) + eval(tmp[2]) + eval(tmp[3]) 
        except:
            pass

alphabetical_name =  result.keys()
alphabetical_name.sort()

for i in alphabetical_name:
    print "Name:%s, Highest score: %d"%(i, result[i])
```

Output:

```
$ python test.py 
Name:brad, Highest score: 15
Name:callum, Highest score: 26
Name:carl, Highest score: 30
Name:hollie, Highest score: 12
Name:kyle, Highest score: 9
```

Answer (score 0):

So i would first of all isolate all the lines:

```
with open('filename') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
```

So i will continue assuming I have a list called lines with the following content:

```
lines = ["callum,10,7,9","carl,10,10,10","hollie,1,4,7","brad,4,8,3","kyle,7,2,0"]
```

Then I will firstly sort the line by name

```
lines = sorted(lines)
```

Then for each line you want to isolate the marks, sort them and print them back:

```
for line in lines:
    #name is what there is before the first comma
    name = line[:line.find(",")]
    #marks are what there is after the second comma and are comma separated
    marks = line[line.find(",")+1:].split(",")
    #sort the marks
    marks = sorted(marks,key=int)

    #if you want to print only the highest
    print "%s,%s"%(name,marks[-1])
```

Comment: it says invalid syntax   name = line.[:line.lfind(",")]  on the first square bracket

Comment: sorry... no . before the bracket... it was just a typo

Comment: fixed that, but its printing their first score in the text file, not their highest score

Comment: can you print marks just before sorting them and just after and paste the result?

Comment: its printing off: brad,4
callum,7
carl,10
hollie,4
kyle,2

Comment: I modified it again.. since you wanted the highest mark you had to take the last element... not the first one. by accessing marks[-1] you will get the last one. now it will work!